# Implicit function evaluation: webbrowser in thread, body always null

Tags: c#, multithreading, implicit

Im trying to get website content using webbrowser in new thread (consoleApplication), then get sring from it, next go to another website and get back to first. My code:

```
   wb.Navigate("https://www.google.com");
    while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete){
         Application.DoEvents();
         Thread.Sleep(10);
    } 
    string content = wb.Document.Body.InnerText; <- here is error(error in screenshoot(regex is good))
//goto next website and get back to first saving all cookies
```

[image: img]

My thread:

```
workerThread=new Thread(new ThreadStart(newWebBrowserStarter));
            workerThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            workerThread.Start();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What about operating on website without losing all cookies?

Comment: Sahee, you have the answer for your original question. Now refactor it for your *new requirements* so that you don't dispose `WebBrowser` control and reuse it.

Comment: There is no error in your screenshot. What does the error message say?

Comment: NullPointerException. Just webBrowser after DocumentDownload return null instead of itsbody.